# Printing an object using cursor in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, cursor

I have this simple collection:

```
use('biblioteca')

db.inventory.insertOne({
    libro: 'El principe de la niebla',
    autor: 'Carlos Ruiz Zafon',
    precio: 20,
    paginas: 240,
    lanzamiento: 1991,
    editorial: 'Planeta'
})
```

I can see the autor if I execute:

```
var cursorArray = db.inventory.find({}).toArray()
print(cursorArray[0].autor)
```

But if I try to print the document using printjson like `printjson(cursorArray[0])`, the result showed is: `[object Object]`

Isn't it supposed to display the document in json format? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Have you tried printjson?

var cursorArray = db.inventory.find({}).toArray()
printjson(cursorArray[0].toJSON())

Comment: @TarunGaur thanks for reply. This doesn´t work. It says: "printjson(cursorArray[0].toJSON()) is not a function".

Comment: I tried it and you are right it gave that error, I updated the code to this and it is working.

`var cursorArray = db. inventory.find({}).toArray();`
`console.log(JSON.stringify(cursorArray[0]));`